# How to call void method from driver

Tags: java

It seems like I can't call the withdraw method.. What did I do wrong?

```
public class BankAccount {
    double balance;

    BankAccount(double openingBalance){
        balance=openingBalance;

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance; 
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){
        balance += amount;
    }
    public void withdraw (double amount){
        if (balance > amount){
            balance -= amount;  
        }else if (amount > balance){
            System.out.print("Error");
        }else if (amount == balance){
            balance = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My driver class

```
public class Driver {

    static BankAccount acc1;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        BankAccount  acc1 = new BankAccount (1500);
        acc1.deposit(1500);
        acc1.withdraw(1000);

        System.out.println("Withdrawl Amount: $" +acc1.withdraw(I GET AN ERROR) +"Deposit: $" +acc1.balance);
```

Comment: Call it from outside of `System.out.println();`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: The method `withdraw(double amount)` in the `BankAccount` class expects a parameter of type `double`. Are you sure you're passing a valid parameter value to this method?

Comment: Yes I am sure I am passing a valid parameter value to the withdraw method

Comment: However, you returned nothing in your `withdraw` function. Then, what do you want to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking acc1.withdraw(...) and trying to append whatever it returns to a String.  Since the withdraw method returns void, that is not valid syntax.  It isn't clear what you really want but if you want to append the return value of withdraw to a String for some reason then withdraw needs to return something.  Maybe you want something like this...

```
public class BankAccount { 
    double balance;

    BankAccount(double openingBalance){
        balance=openingBalance;
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){
        balance += amount;
    }
    public double withdraw (double amount){
        if (balance > amount){
            balance -= amount;
        }else if (amount > balance){
            System.out.print("Error");
        }else if (amount == balance){
            balance = 0;
        }
        // you can return the amount, or the balance, or whatever you want here...
        return amount;
    }
}
```

One way to invoke the method...

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        BankAccount  acc1 = new BankAccount (1500);

        System.out.println("After Withdrawing Amount: $" +acc1.withdraw(50) +" The New Balance: $" +acc1.balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so where do you return it?

Comment: Anywhere you like.  In your example the method was called from your Driver class.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are really trying to do but the problem with your original code is that you can't invoke a method which returns void and append the result of that a String or anything else.  The method isn't returning anything so there is nothing to append.